# How to make a list item width as body width instead of container width

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, listitem

Hi i am trying to set the width of list item to browsers width, when i set width to 100% then it is taking parent's width, but i want it to take whole browser width as that list item width.

i have used following code for the child item of list item div

```
      .submenu {
       position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
       background: #ddf0f9;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #2ea0cb;
        z-index: -1;
           white-space: nowrap;
           padding: 0;
          }
```

it doesn't worked, it is taking parent element width as it's width.

similar to mashable.com submenu

Comment: What browser support do you need

Comment: Please add some code or jsfiddle please.

Comment: set position absolute to the ul. be sure the container doesn't have a relative position.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
.classname{
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mashable.com set `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;` to the list item, and does not set a `position` for any of its parents. Since a absolute positioned element positions itself based on its *first positioned* parent, the list item will have the width of the highest parent (the `body`).
If you don't need positioning for any of the list item's parents then you can use that method.